# React Router: Add entry to history without changing route

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Using React Router, what's the best way of pushing a new entry to the history so it updates the URL, but *without* triggering a new route?

The `Navigation.replaceWith()` mixin method seems to do the opposite of what I need.

Answer (score 3):

Not really familiar with React-Router's API, but you could use pure javascript to do that.

```
window.history.pushState({}, '', 'https://stackoverflow.com/new-url-here');
```

More answers here: [Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)